# Ionic 2 / Angular 2 : How to import external jQuery Libraries ($ is not defined)

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic2

I am building my Ionic 2 application and i want to use the Angular 2 Datatable plugin (https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables).

I have imported jQuery and the Data tables JS files through NPM.

```
npm install jquery --save 
npm install datatables.net --save 
npm install datatables.net-dt --save 
npm install angular-datatables --save
```

Now since im in ionic2 and not able to see angular-cli.json, i have imported the JS file for data tree and Jquery + the CSS to my index.html

```
<link href="../node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

In my home.html page i have added the table i want to format

```
<table id="myTable" datatable class="row-border hover">
```

And finally in Home.ts i have the following

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  $(document).ready(
    function(){
       $("#myTable").css("font-size:30px;");
    }
  );
 }
```

Finally here is my error:
[ReferenceError: $ is not defined ReferenceError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agfsh.png)

I am not mistaken it seems that in my context the $ sign is not resolved as "Jquery" for the dataTable library JS files which is triggering the error.

Can someone please help out?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: $ now is not available to jQuery

Comment: try this 'declare var $:any;' before @Component

Comment: hi @bipinpatel, no it didnt work

Comment: hi @RomanC, does it mean this is currently impossible with ionic2?

Comment: maybe install @types/jquery and import $ from 'jquery'; instead of * as $

Comment: on a side note this is like getting 3 libraries just for data tables. Your file will be huge and slow to load. Trying another library would be optimal